# As a Brazilian, can I travel to Mexico during the one-month grace period of my J-1 Visa?

Tags: usa, mexico, j1-visas, brazilian-citizens

I have a J-1 Visa valid until August 31. After my Visa expires, I'm planning to enjoy the first half of my one-month grace period by staying in the US for 15 days. After that, I plan to travel in Mexico for 15 more days. So I'm planning to take a flight from Mexico City to São Paulo. But I'm not sure if I can visit Mexico during my grace period.

Can you please help me to know if it is possible to visit Mexico during the one-month grace period of my J-1 Visa?

Comment: Brazilians require a visa to visit Mexico.  My understanding is that holders of a _valid_ US visa are exempt from needing a visa, however if your US visa has expired then it may not be sufficient to enter Mexico.